# HTML/CSS style tags not working

Tags: html, css

For some reason, none of my style tags are being picked up either in the embedded CSS or HTML. Neither the font-family changes are not being taken into effect nor the `border-top: 5px solid black;` line. Any tips?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        My Resume
    </title>
<style type=“text/css”>

#ob {
    border-top: 5px solid black;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h1 style=“font-family: sans-serif”>
            <strong>Corey Schnedl </strong>
        </h1>

        <h4 style=“font-family: Sans-Serif”>
            <strong> XXXXXXXXXXX / XXXXXXXX / XXXXX / XXXXX </strong>
            <br>
            <strong>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</strong>
        </h4>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h3 style=“font-family:Arial”>
            <strong>Objective</strong>
        </h3>
        <p>
            To obtain an entry-level position as a Java software developer.
    </div>

</body> 


</html>
```

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120486/quotes-problem-in-mavericks-or-textedit.

Comment: Run your HTML through a validator.

Comment: Textastic is awesome, I've never had it crash.   It doesn't appear that you have given any of the HTML elements a id, so that's why your `#ob` CSS rule isn't doing anything. Also, http://www.w3schools.com is a great resource for learning and exploration into HTML, CSS and beyond.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use plain text quotes. This `"` not `“`

Four occurrences that break your code:

- `<style type=“text/css”>`
- `<h1 style=“font-family: sans-serif”>`
- `<h4 style=“font-family: Sans-Serif”>`
- `<h3 style=“font-family:Arial”>`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>
            My Resume
        </title>
    <style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    #ob {
        border-top: 5px solid black;
    }
    
    </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1 style="font-family: sans-serif">
                <strong>Corey Schnedl </strong>
            </h1>
    
            <h4 style="font-family: Sans-Serif">
                <strong> XXXXXXXXXXX / XXXXXXXX / XXXXX / XXXXX </strong>
                <br>
                <strong>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</strong>
            </h4>
        </div>
    
        <div>
            <h3 style="font-family:Arial">
                <strong>Objective</strong>
            </h3>
            <p>
                To obtain an entry-level position as a Java software developer.
        </div>
    
    </body> 
    
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Wow thank you, I didn't even realize, but every time I typed a " it changed it to a “ automatically even though I have plain-text selected in the settings for TextEdit.

Answer (score 1):

Edit this:

```
<style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and this

```
style="font-family:'Arial';"
```

put a semicolon at the end of every `style` attribute

Here is your edited page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        My Resume
    </title>
<style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
#ob {
    border-top: 5px solid black;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h1 style="font-family: sans-serif;">
            <strong>Corey Schnedl </strong>
        </h1>

        <h4 style="font-family: Sans-Serif;">
            <strong> XXXXXXXXXXX / XXXXXXXX / XXXXX / XXXXX </strong>
            <br>
            <strong>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</strong>
        </h4>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h3 style="font-family:Arial;">
            <strong>Objective</strong>
        </h3>
        <p>
            To obtain an entry-level position as a Java software developer.
    </div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Using a validator is a good idea to check your syntex mistakes. Here https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: You also forgot the two other ones. :)

Comment: There are four occurrences of the bug and with only one style, the semicolon isn't required :)

Comment: He is trying only one right now, but will add others too.It's best to follow best practice from the start.

Comment: Why are quotes required around "Arial"?

Comment: well, they are not required around `Arial` and `sans-serif`. I use custom fonts all the time so I just put those out of habit. Sorry about that.

Comment: But it is good to use because some fonts require that and some not, but better to use them all the time